# Bootstrap dropdowns not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is for my nav bar. The "about us" dropdown is not working and the toggle button when the window gets smaller isn't either.

Here's the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="help.html">Home</a>
    </div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">ABOUT US <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">DOCTORS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OUR STAFF</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PAYMENT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PATIENT FORMS</a></li>
  </ul>

  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: working - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/wk5cgkxd/

Comment: there is one `</ul>` too much and you can remove `class="container-fluid"` it you want to use this, then you should put rows and columns in there before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zanon/uLn1apr6/).

Your code has only one error: the extra `</ul>` tag at the end.

However, this do not trigger the issue that you are complaining (dropdown and toogle button not working). I can reproduce this only if you miss adding the jQuery library or the Bootstrap JavaScript (that is used to create those effects and depends on jQuery).

You can get them following these links:
jQuery: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js
Bootstrap JS: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js

Pay attention: the Bootstrap JS must match the version of the Bootstrap CSS.